# How to find overlapping controls that I added to form?

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, winforms, windows-forms-designer

I've simply added a control to my form and now I can't even see it on the form. But it is still there. How can I find it?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In situations that it is not possible to simply click on design surface and select your control, you can select your control using either of these options:

**Document Outline Window**

You can open Document Outline Window using menu View → Other Windows → Document Outline Also using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> shortcut.

[image]

The Document Outline is most useful when you need to put design focus on controls that are deeply embedded within other controls, or that might be hard to select using a mouse or the TAB key.

- View the logical structure of a Form or a UserControl.
- Put user input focus on deeply nested controls that may be hard to select on the Form itself or the UserControl itself.
- Move controls from one parent to another parent.
- Locate controls that may be visually hidden by other controls.

**Propertie Window**

You can open Propertie Window using menu View → Properties Window Also using <kbd>F4</kbd> shortcut.

[image]

You can select the control form the drop-down which contains all controls.

Answer (score 2):

Or use the Document Outline window. You can also drag your controls here if they were accidentally misplaced or if you want to change the order of the docked controls.

[image]