# Lost buttons in design view

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

[image]

buttons problem in design view

Code for buttons is present in code file and the project is compiled successfully, but after compiling buttons are not showing in the form. when i try to create a new button it offers me button 4, where are my previous 3 buttons, when code is present here.. please help me on this

Answer (score 3):

Go to the ***Design View*** and click anywhere on the *Form* and press **F4** (*View -> Properties Window*)

[image]

Here, as you see above, you'll be able to see all the *Controls* that you've added to your **Form**.

Comment: I have lost data in VS, they warned me but i ignored and continue.. Now i'm not getting my buttons back, though they already exist in code.. Anyways thanks for your help.

Comment: did you keep a backup of your project? your designer.cs must have omitted the lines when you ignored the warnings and continued.

Comment: try removing these lines from the **Form1.Designer.cs** 
            `this.button1 = new System.Windows.Forms.Button(); ` , `this.Controls.Add(this.button1); ` & 
        `private System.Windows.Forms.Button button1; `, similarly do the same for the other buttons you're facing problems with(button2, button3) . And then you can add new buttons on the form starting from `button1, button2.. ` again

Comment: You can also use Document outline window. Like this [How to find the Control that I added to Form?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32331696/how-to-find-the-control-that-i-added-to-form)