# Unable to select a specific control in Windows Forms

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, windows-forms-designer

I'm working in a legacy software. It was written probably 10+ years ago and never ported to newer technology or never redesigned. It is a Windows Forms desktop software on .NET 3.5.

I'm trying to redesign a particular window of the software. The window consists of many controls and most of them are hidden when the window is launched. Only after certain user interaction reveals certain controls.

There is a particular control which I cannot select by clicking on it in the Designer window. When I select all controls by Ctrl+A, that control is selected. The control is shown below:

[image]

It has no text. The text is populated later.

When no control is selected, clicking on the bounding rectangle of the control has no effect. It selects the parent panel. I tried sending the parent panel to back, but still I cannot select this control.

So how to select this control in the Designer view?

Comment: You can use Document Outline Window - Also you can use the combo box in Properties Window. Take a look at this post: [How to find the Control that I added to Form?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32331696/how-to-find-the-control-that-i-added-to-form). Using Document Outline Windows is preferred.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do you know the name of the control?

If so, right-click on any other control, and select *Properties* to bring up the Properties window. You can now select any control (by name) on the form from the dropdown at the top of this window.

[image: Properties window]

Answer (score 2):

Open the Properties Window (using: alt, view, Properties Window).  Click on the property name drop down list right at the top.  Then use your cursor up and down keys until the control you want is highlighted.  You can then change the settings for the control using the relevant properties.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Well there is a simple trick that you can follow:

`Right click` your form => `Properties` => In the properties window there is a `drop-down` at the top that shows all the controls in your form, you can choose your control from that list and change its property (maybe add text to make it select-able).