# Form shrinks on smaller screen in VS. How do I get groupboxes that are now outside the form's border?

Tags: c#, winforms, size

I'm on the road at the moment and I've opened a WinForms project in VS.
The form was designed to run on a full hd display, so VS has shrunk it for my laptop display. I'm trying to put all the groupboxes in a panel so I can run it on my laptop, but some of them are now outside the form's border. How can I grab them?

Comment: [How to find the Control that I added to Form?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32331696/how-to-find-the-control-that-i-added-to-form)

Comment: Also temporarily you can set `AutoScroll` property of form to `true`, then you can find those lost controls.

Answer (score 0):

Use  [TableLayoutPanel Control](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd492143.aspx)  Because i have also face same issue but when you design winform using TableLayoutPanel  then the size of the form increase or decrease then don't affect on winform. it's resize the every control on form as per screen size.

Hope it will help you thank you.

Comment: I'm not the downvoter, but I think setting `AutoScroll` to `true` is a better option. When the controls go beyond form's boundary, `TableLayoutPanel` will not help much.

Comment: @RezaAghaei thank you so much but when the size of screen is BiG and if you don't wan't  the scrolling form then you have only single option that is use TableLayoutPanel Control beacuse it's able to resize all control as per form size.

Comment: I understand what you mean. When you want to size controls by *percentage* you can use `TableLayoutPanel`. This way, you should have a docked `TableLayoutPanel` with *percent* row and column styles and put some docked controls in cells. You can make the answer more useful by adding more details.

Comment: @RezaAghaei is's depend on UX team you are also right  AutoScroll true is one also solution of this but it's not proper way to solving problem.