# Menu Strip in form with Split container (currently being fixed to either panel)

Tags: c#, winforms, menustrip, splitcontainer

[image]

As you can see in the image, my menustrip is being fixed to panel B. What i'm aiming for is to naturally have the menustrip not be in the splitpanel and be docked to the top of the window with no parent.

I can't seem to get it out of the splitpanel.
What's the best course of action here? I'm new to win forms.

Thank you

Comment: Currently your `MenuStrip` is child of that panel. Use [*Document Outline*](http://stackoverflow.com/a/32331827/3110834) window to bring it out and set is as child of the `Form`. To show *Document Outline Window* press *Ctrl + Alt + T* or go to *VIEW → Other Windows → Document Outline* menu.

Comment: @RezaAghaei That was it! Can you please change your comment to an answer so I can accept it please? Thanks

Comment: @RezaAghaei I have the right panel set to Dock = Fill, as it's a listview with images, and I naturally want it to grow when the window resizes. However, now it's being cropped off slightly at the top due to the menu strip. is that possible to fix?

Comment: @RezaAghaei Nevermind. Solved via anchoring to the top, left, right and bottom and setting dock = none. Thanks again

Comment: You can use `Dock = Fill` with no problem, it's enough to bring the `ListView` to the front of the `MenuStrip` using the *Document Outline* window.

Comment: Thanks for your offer, but since I've posted a similar answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/32331827/3110834) I prefer to not post my comment as an answer. If you want to keep the the question, feel free to post your own answer based on my comment.

Comment: By the way, if you liked the linked answer, you can vote for it and its question to make them more popular to be more useful for future readers :)

Comment: @RezaAghaei Done and done. Thanks again