# WinForms add Menu inside Panel

Tags: vb.net, winforms, menu, menustrip

I am doing and WinForms VB.Net 4.6 Application.

I have the main form with his MenuStrip Control. Inside a Child Form a have a panel docked in left side of the Form. I need to had a simple menú inside this Panel.

I have tried with MenuStrip, what I do not found a way to put it inside a Panel. I have tried with UltratoolbarsManager from Infragistics, but it does not fit.

If there a way to add a menú using a Panel as Container?

Thanks

Comment: You can host `MenuStrip` in any container control including panel. When dropping the `MenuStrip` onto your form, make sure the panel control is active in design surface. Also if by any mistake you put the `MenuStrip` in another place like your form, using the [*Document Outline*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32331827/3110834) window, move it to the container which you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you drag the menustrip inside your panel you can acheive your goal...
alternatively, you can add your menustrip inside your panel by code:

```
panel1.Controls.Add(menuStrip1);
```