# C# Winform moving buttons to Tab Control

Tags: c#, winforms, tabs

So I have winform app that already has a bunch of buttons on it that function. To clean up the UI some I wanted to be able to move those existing buttons onto tabs. But it looks like it wont let me just drag the buttons over. I know I can create new things on these tab windows, but would like to just move things over so i dont have to write all new features of the app. Any solutions?

Comment: Check that the `Dock` property of the control in question is NOT set to `Fill`.  When set to Fill, you will not be able to move the control.  You can set the dock property back to fill after moving.

Comment: Use document outline window: [How to find overlapping controls that I added to form?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32331827/3110834)

Comment: You wouldn't need to create a new function the button already has provided you're using a 'click' event for the button. If you still can't move the button, delete it, create a new button inside the 'tab control' and attach the event to the button via the (design) form or in code. To do it in code you can just do "button.Click += HandleButtonClick".